# iphone app if backgrounded and then killed from fast access bar, on next restart will crash with SIGKILL and iphone will turn black

Tags: iphone, background, switching

So the iphone app that I have created...

1. if it is backgrounded for another app or something...
2. And then is killed using the fast action switcher.
3. next restart of app crashes app
4. Iphone turns black screen with status bar at top and just gets stuck there.
5. If I then double tap home button I can see a faint line come up to slightly show where perhaps the fast app switcher is..

crazy weird.  though Id like to handle this correctly..  Ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try running it without the debugger attached.